# Do i need c3p0 for Springboot 2.x?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am migrating a existing Spring application (non Spring boot) to Springboot 2.x. I see there is a `c3p0.properties` file with following configuration: `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ExcludeIdentityToken=true`. What does this does exactly? Do I need this if I am using Springboot 2.x? Or do I need to setup something else configuration in my `application.properties` file?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.x use HikariCp as a default JDBC connection pool. It is faster then c3p0.
You should use Hikari.

You can read about it compared with c2p0:

[Hikari vs other CPs](https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp)

Spring Boot will autoconfig it to you, but you can customize it (for example in application.properties)

For the `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ExcludeIdentityToken` visit the documentation page's Jmx configuration section

[JMX configuration](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#jmx_configuration_and_management)

Comment: So I dont need the `c3p0.properties` file and the configuration when changing over to Springboot 2.x ?

Comment: no, you dont. you can use hikaricp configuration instead for hikari specific properties. for generals, like driverClassName, url etc just use spring.datasource... props